# Why did I have to manually set the .value from the .text on losing focus in an unbound textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an unbound textbox to accept the delete older than: number of days. It is in the report header. I set it to 30 days but I want the user to be able to change it. I was banging my head trying to figure out why entering 40 was not being accepted and it reverted back to 30 every time.  I finally decided on using the lost_focus event to set .value to .text.  That worked.

Further research showed that when the textbox get's focus text and value are both the same, 30 in my case.  Changing the number in the text box to 40 shows the values of text at 40 and value at 30.  Unless I specifically set Value to the value of text Access changes text to the value of value.  This is different behavior than other places in Access such as forms.

Can anyone tell me why this might be?  I can't find any setting that might do this. Is it because it's in a report header?  what is the difference between this and every other text box I've ever used?

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share issues with a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. If you have a particular issue after [researching](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) existing answers, please [edit] your post to share some background info and a **[mcve] of your code** and relevant data. More tips here: *"[ask]"* and in the [help/on-topic], as well as this [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the sites' top user.  Good luck!

Comment: Ever heard of paragraphs or linebreaks ;) Why don't you use a form (pop-up) to enter this value?

Comment: @ashleedawg  Why are you emphasizing *"write their own code"* and **"specific problem"** in your canned response?  Besides poor formatting, I don't see the a big problem with the question.  The user is *not* asking for code and the specific problem is about the two textbox properties described in the question.

Comment: You can't attach files to a Stack Overflow question and your question does not give any information how to reproduce what you have. What's more, I can see that this question has anything to do with coding - it looks like it belongs in an end-user venue?

Comment: I understood and reproduced the behavior.  I simply created a dummy report on an existing table and then added a couple unbound textboxes.  It behaved just the the OP said.  Poor formatting makes for a poor question, but it's not that hard folks if you're familiar with Access Reports.

Comment: Well there are two paragraphs here, one describing the question and the other asking why.  In retrospect one more line break between the two.  I thought I had uploaded a small example but obviously I was wrong but that would have helped alot.  This CERTAINLY is not an end user issue and I have not idea why anyone thinks this is not a programmer writing my own code unless the behavior happens to be in something that takes near minimal coding.  Anyway, thank you C Perkins for taking the time.

Comment: I have edited the question to try to answer the criticism I got.  The downvotes got me a warning that i might get banned when I tried to ask another question.  When they say stack overflow is unfriendly this might be why.  Thanks again to C Perkins for coming to my defense.  I hope my editing at least helps answer the paragraph question and I did take out parts of the original message where I ranted at odd behavior. I will leave that out on any new questions I ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a "best practices" viewpoint, Access Reports are not intended to be used interactively despite the ability to manipulate some unbound controls.  Although workarounds can be implemented that function sufficiently well, such solutions are often incomplete and buggy and function differently depending on the active view: Report View vs. Print Preview.  Appropriate design patterns include using Access Forms for specifying report options which then open the Report in a *static configuration*.

This may not satisfy the question "Why?" if seeking a deeper answer as to why Microsoft implemented inconsistent binding behavior in Access, or why they allowed interactive controls in reports at all if they don't behave the same way as in forms.  But Access has plenty of other quirky behaviors that have no known/published explanation.

Regarding the priority of the Value property updating the Text property (and not vice versa):  Value is the key field because it contains the *actual data* for the control (bound or unbound).  Although it is natural to have a single control for both display and input (uh, that's how almost all controls work), the processes of displaying data and parsing user input are two distinct functions. The visual representation returned by the Text property can be manipulated using the various formatting properties, and technically could display an incomplete representation of the underlying Value data.  If there are any conflicts between the stored Value property and the Text property, it is natural that the existing Value property has precedent.

My guess is that the automatic binding behavior was "relaxed" for reports to allow more flexible custom reporting output.  First consider an Access Form in Datasheet view: An unbound Form control shows the *same value for all* records.  Even if the control is edited while on a particular row, the updated value is displayed for all rows. The same control object is essentially *repainted* for each row and there is no concept of individual instances of the control that can hold different values.  Bound controls have built-in code that repaint the control with data from the particular row, but there are still *not* multiple instances each "holding" the individual values.  The visual output differs from an intuitive object-oriented paradigm where our minds what to assign each visual row its own in-memory instance of the controls--it just doesn't work like that in Access.

Unlike the Form behavior just described, the Report's Print Preview (and actual printed output) allows unbound controls to display different data per row using the Detail_Format() event.  Within the Detail_Format() event, one can set the Value property of a control at which time the Text property is automatically updated according to various formatting properties.  This update Text is then output for the current row.  Perhaps (just guessing) that this behavior would not function properly if the Text property updated the value property.  I suspect it would cause recursive events during report generation.  Because reports are not meant to be interactive, relevant text-input parsing code was "disconnected" so that it doesn't behave like on a form.

All that explanation doesn't make Access any less frustrating nor remove its limitations, but at least learn to adapt and design things in the "Access-esque" way rather than fighting it.

Comment: Beautifully  written and the second the last paragraph explains why this behavior makes sense.  The difference between Value and Text property is why I got to the work around I did but, until you talked about detail_format(), I could not make any sense of why text would not update value.  I have done lot's of coding in C#, VB6 and way back in other languages but have only done Access coding periodically.  I normally would not have thought of putting an interactive button on a report but they made it so "easy".  Anyway, thank you for your thoughtful help on learning Access-esque.

Comment: By the way I don't see a place as logical place to put this code.  The failedaccess is a file automatically filled when someone attempts to get into a database they are not authorized for.  There is no edit of the data. The report has no parameters to set before seeing it.  The table just needs to be cleaned out every once in awhile. I could have a form to do this but I can't think of a place where it would not be less obvious and therefor not used. Any ideas would be helpful

Comment: Your coding experience sounds like mine.  Maybe that's why I got your question when others didn't.  I used to expect Access to have been designed more like other .Net framework or other OO platforms.  Somehow Access continues to prove very useful--it's a clunky tool that can't be replaced without piecing together a lot of other incomplete tools.  As for designing Reports, I have done the exact same thing, expecting it to behave in an obvious, intuitive way just to find its behavior is often just stupid.

Comment: The suggestion to use a Form for spawning a Report is just a common pattern in Access, but you can also use VBA to manipulate and generate Reports.  Macros can be set to automatically execute when the database is opened, etc. There are multiple way to generate the report. I am a bit confused though... if the Report has no parameters, why are you trying to set a value called "older than: number of days" using an interactive control?  That sounds like a "parameter" to me.  I'm also a bit lost on your comment... don't understand whether the report is for the user or an admin.  Best of luck.

Comment: The system was built by a non-programmer and I'm trying to get it more professional without rewriting the whole thing. It is really a set of databases with a switchboard like database to start.  That has an employees database that has a non-normalized (booo) set of boolean fields that allow or disallow access to the various other programs, each of which is a separate database.  The users could still go into any of the databases individually without regard to the access rights defined in the switchboard. I separated the front and back ends but users could still go into any by clicking on them

Comment: so..I a small bit of code in an frmBegin that gets the username, compares it to the employees table to find out if they are allowed.  I want to know who might actually think they need direct access and why so i added a small logging table for failed attempts.  The report is a list of failed accesses by name, date and program used to find out what people are attempting. It should not grow forever so the delete older than runs an db.execute delete * where attemptdate < now() - daysOlderThan (not exact code).  I hope that clears it up.

Comment: by the way is there any way to get rid of the three negatives that I don't believe should be there given your easy understanding of the issues?

Comment: Not sure what "three negatives" refers to.  Remember that I don't have the actual database file and although I get the gist of what you describe, the finer details are still beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is to design a form with the unbound combo boxes and have your data displayed in a subreport. I like to design my reports so that when values are updated the query for the recordsource of the report is generated doing this requires 2 queries to exist, one with all data possible and a filtered one as subreport recordsource. This will control the data for printing and also allow users to close or navigate away from the report and return to the data later.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_AfterUpdate()
Dim Query1 as Object
Dim Temp_Name as Variant
Temp_Name = SubReport.SourceObject
SubReport.SourceObject = Empty
Set Query1 = Me.Form.Application.DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0).QueryDefs ("SubReport_Query")
Query1.SQL = "Select * Unfiltered_Query WHERE Field1 <= " ComboBox1 & ";"
SubReport.SourceObject = Temp_Name
End Sub
```